# replicating openssl encryption in .NET?

Tags: .net, openssl, aes

I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a good way to replicate the following openssl command line in .NET? I'm not looking for someone to write the code, just suggest the best method to use.  I have RijndaelManaged working doing AES 256 CBC mode and can base64 encode it, etc. But, I'm unclear on how openssl is generating\using "salt"  - is the salt a part of the result base64 encoded output?

```
$ echo 1234 | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:<passphrase>
```

Any pointers to decent documentation on openssl commandline? (I don't see salt or aes-256-cbc on http://openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html )

EDIT:

OK, found the documentation for openssl enc at http://openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html# - just trying to grok it. :)

EDIT2:

I think this is closer to what I am needing ( http://deusty.blogspot.com/2009/04/decrypting-openssl-aes-files-in-c.html )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL is basically some dlls with and executable over them. There is an old project [OpenSSL.Net](http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/) on sourceforge to bind them in C# maybe you could start there.

Comment: upvote since this is a decent option.  I would prefer to stick to using the .net framework crypto classes though.

Comment: Actually I'm going to mark this as answer, since it probably would have been the sensible way to do it.  Finally got it working how I wanted though :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452422/openssl-using-only-net-classes/5454692#5454692

Answer (score 1):

The answers to [openssl des3 decrypting in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759722/openssl-des3-decrypting-in-java) should get you going.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful, but would be nice to find an AES example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with [OpenSSL Library for .NET](https://www.didisoft.com/openssl-net/examples/cipher/)

```
DidiSoft.OpenSsl.OpenSslCipher cipher = new DidiSoft.OpenSsl.OpenSslCipher();
bool isBase64 = true;
string encrypted = cipher.EncryptString(CipherAlgorithm.Aes_256_Cfb, "1234", 
                                        "<passphrase>", isBase64);
```

Disclaimer: I work for DidiSoft