# OpenSSL encryption using .NET classes

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm looking to create a class that uses the .NET libraries that is compatible with OpenSSL.  I'm aware there is an OpenSSL.Net wrapper, but I would prefer to avoid referencing 3rd party\unmanaged code. I'm not looking for a discussion of whether this is the right choice, but there are reasons for it.

Currently I have the following, which I believe should be compatible with OpenSSL - it effectively does what I believe OpenSSL does from the OpenSSL documentation.  However even when just using this class to do both the encryption and decryption, I'm getting the following error:

```
[CryptographicException] Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
```

I have stepped through the code and verified that the salt\key\iv are all the same during the encryption and decryption process.

See below for sample class and call to do encrypt decrypt. Any ideas or pointers would be welcome.

```
public class Protection
    {
        public string OpenSSLEncrypt(string plainText, string passphrase)
        {
            // generate salt
            byte[] key, iv;
            byte[] salt = new byte[8];
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            rng.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
            DeriveKeyAndIV(passphrase, salt, out key, out iv);
            // encrypt bytes
            byte[] encryptedBytes = EncryptStringToBytesAes(plainText, key, iv);
            // add salt as first 8 bytes
            byte[] encryptedBytesWithSalt = new byte[salt.Length + encryptedBytes.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, encryptedBytesWithSalt, 0, salt.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytesWithSalt, salt.Length, encryptedBytes.Length);
            // base64 encode
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytesWithSalt);
        }

        public string OpenSSLDecrypt(string encrypted, string passphrase)
        {
            // base 64 decode
            byte[] encryptedBytesWithSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
            // extract salt (first 8 bytes of encrypted)
            byte[] salt = new byte[8];
            byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[encryptedBytesWithSalt.Length - salt.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedBytesWithSalt, 0, salt, 0, salt.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedBytesWithSalt, salt.Length, encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
            // get key and iv
            byte[] key, iv;
            DeriveKeyAndIV(passphrase, salt, out key, out iv);
            return DecryptStringFromBytesAes(encryptedBytes, key, iv);
        }

        private static void DeriveKeyAndIV(string passphrase, byte[] salt, out byte[] key, out byte[] iv)
        {
            // generate key and iv
            List<byte> concatenatedHashes = new List<byte>(48);

            byte[] password = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passphrase);
            byte[] currentHash = new byte[0];
            MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
            bool enoughBytesForKey = false;
            // See http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html#KEY_DERIVATION_ALGORITHM
            while (!enoughBytesForKey)
            {
                int preHashLength = currentHash.Length + password.Length + salt.Length;
                byte[] preHash = new byte[preHashLength];

                Buffer.BlockCopy(currentHash, 0, preHash, 0, currentHash.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(password, 0, preHash, currentHash.Length, password.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, preHash, currentHash.Length + password.Length, salt.Length);

                currentHash = md5.ComputeHash(preHash);
                concatenatedHashes.AddRange(currentHash);

                if (concatenatedHashes.Count >= 48)
                    enoughBytesForKey = true;
            }

            key = new byte[32];
            iv = new byte[16];
            concatenatedHashes.CopyTo(0, key, 0, 32);
            concatenatedHashes.CopyTo(32, iv, 0, 16);

            md5.Clear();
            md5 = null;
        }

        static byte[] EncryptStringToBytesAes(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("iv");

            // Declare the stream used to encrypt to an in memory
            // array of bytes.
            MemoryStream msEncrypt;

            // Declare the RijndaelManaged object
            // used to encrypt the data.
            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

            try
            {
                // Create a RijndaelManaged object
                // with the specified key and IV.
                aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged { Key = key, IV = iv, Mode = CipherMode.CBC, KeySize = 256, BlockSize = 256 };


                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {

                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        swEncrypt.Flush();
                        swEncrypt.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
                if (aesAlg != null)
                    aesAlg.Clear();
            }

            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }

        static string DecryptStringFromBytesAes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("iv");

            // Declare the RijndaelManaged object
            // used to decrypt the data.
            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext;

            try
            {
                // Create a RijndaelManaged object
                // with the specified key and IV.
                aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged { Key = key, IV = iv, Mode = CipherMode.CBC, KeySize = 256, BlockSize = 256};

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                            srDecrypt.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
                if (aesAlg != null)
                    aesAlg.Clear();
            }

            return plaintext;
        }
    }
```

I then call this to test it:

```
Protection protection = new Protection();
const string passphrase = "<passphrase>";
string encrypted = protection.OpenSSLEncrypt(jobid, passphrase);
string decrypted = protection.OpenSSLDecrypt(encrypted, passphrase);
```

Comment: If you are trying to achieve AES the block size is incorrect, it is 128-bits for AES (`BlockSize = 256`). I don't see any mention of PKCS#7 padding and I believe that is an OpenSSL default for AES. Also the usual practice is to create a random iv on encryption and prepend it to the encrypted data. On decryption pull the iv and use it for decryption.

Comment: I need to implement the same but with 3DES. Any suggestion? I'm trying actually to implement that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Finally figured this one out.  In the event someone needs to integrate openssl and .NET without using the openssl wrappers,  I'll share the results here.

1) The main issue with my original code (as in the question) is that you must initialize the BlockSize and KeySize on your RijndaelManaged instance BEFORE setting the key or IV.

2) I also had BlockSize set to 256 when it should only be 128

3) The remainder of my issue came to the fact that openssl puts and expects "Salted__" onto the front of the salt before appending the encrypted string and then base64 encoding it. (I saw this initially in the openssl documentation with respect to file encryption but didn't think it did it when doing it directly through commandline - Apparently I was wrong!!  Note also the capitalization of the S in Salted!)

With that all in mind, here is my "fixed" code:

```
public class Protection
    {
        public string OpenSSLEncrypt(string plainText, string passphrase)
        {
            // generate salt
            byte[] key, iv;
            byte[] salt = new byte[8];
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            rng.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
            DeriveKeyAndIV(passphrase, salt, out key, out iv);
            // encrypt bytes
            byte[] encryptedBytes = EncryptStringToBytesAes(plainText, key, iv);
            // add salt as first 8 bytes
            byte[] encryptedBytesWithSalt = new byte[salt.Length + encryptedBytes.Length + 8];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Salted__"), 0, encryptedBytesWithSalt, 0, 8);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, encryptedBytesWithSalt, 8, salt.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytesWithSalt, salt.Length + 8, encryptedBytes.Length);
            // base64 encode
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytesWithSalt);
        }

        public string OpenSSLDecrypt(string encrypted, string passphrase)
        {
            // base 64 decode
            byte[] encryptedBytesWithSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
            // extract salt (first 8 bytes of encrypted)
            byte[] salt = new byte[8];
            byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[encryptedBytesWithSalt.Length - salt.Length - 8];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedBytesWithSalt, 8, salt, 0, salt.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedBytesWithSalt, salt.Length + 8, encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
            // get key and iv
            byte[] key, iv;
            DeriveKeyAndIV(passphrase, salt, out key, out iv);
            return DecryptStringFromBytesAes(encryptedBytes, key, iv);
        }

        private static void DeriveKeyAndIV(string passphrase, byte[] salt, out byte[] key, out byte[] iv)
        {
            // generate key and iv
            List<byte> concatenatedHashes = new List<byte>(48);

            byte[] password = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passphrase);
            byte[] currentHash = new byte[0];
            MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
            bool enoughBytesForKey = false;
            // See http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html#KEY_DERIVATION_ALGORITHM
            while (!enoughBytesForKey)
            {
                int preHashLength = currentHash.Length + password.Length + salt.Length;
                byte[] preHash = new byte[preHashLength];

                Buffer.BlockCopy(currentHash, 0, preHash, 0, currentHash.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(password, 0, preHash, currentHash.Length, password.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, preHash, currentHash.Length + password.Length, salt.Length);

                currentHash = md5.ComputeHash(preHash);
                concatenatedHashes.AddRange(currentHash);

                if (concatenatedHashes.Count >= 48)
                    enoughBytesForKey = true;
            }

            key = new byte[32];
            iv = new byte[16];
            concatenatedHashes.CopyTo(0, key, 0, 32);
            concatenatedHashes.CopyTo(32, iv, 0, 16);

            md5.Clear();
            md5 = null;
        }

        static byte[] EncryptStringToBytesAes(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("iv");

            // Declare the stream used to encrypt to an in memory
            // array of bytes.
            MemoryStream msEncrypt;

            // Declare the RijndaelManaged object
            // used to encrypt the data.
            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

            try
            {
                // Create a RijndaelManaged object
                // with the specified key and IV.
                aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, KeySize = 256, BlockSize = 128, Key = key, IV = iv };

                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {

                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        swEncrypt.Flush();
                        swEncrypt.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
                if (aesAlg != null)
                    aesAlg.Clear();
            }

            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }

        static string DecryptStringFromBytesAes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("iv");

            // Declare the RijndaelManaged object
            // used to decrypt the data.
            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext;

            try
            {
                // Create a RijndaelManaged object
                // with the specified key and IV.
                aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged {Mode = CipherMode.CBC, KeySize = 256, BlockSize = 128, Key = key, IV = iv};

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                            srDecrypt.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
                if (aesAlg != null)
                    aesAlg.Clear();
            }

            return plaintext;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, do you have the equivalent openssl command line arguments to do the opposite tasks? For example I encrypt a message with your code, what is the command I should use to decrypt from openssl?

Comment: The equivalent command to decrypt with openssl is `openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in encrypted_file.txt > decrypted_file.txt`

Comment: That's a dead link! Here's the correct one: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html

Comment: Another suggestion would be to change and refactor MD5 md5 = MD5.Create(); to SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create(); If using a version of open sll that still uses MD5 you can then pass "-md SHA256"

Comment: Can MD5 be used with CipherMode.CBC and PaddingMode.Zeros ? I'm having trouble making this work with a specific key - I posted another question about it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388009/aes-decryption-using-a-specific-key-not-working

Answer (score 2):

Afraid there are issues with this latest code as well as OpenSSLDecrypt results in an error:

> Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for >more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
>
> It occurs at the closen paren of this code:
>
> using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))" in 'static string DecryptStringFromBytesAes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)

I had no idea it would be this hard to encrypt a blob of text from one computer, then send it for storage and decryption to another.

Answer (score 0):

10 years after, I opened a similar question
[It is possible to decrypt AES password protected file in C# / dotNet 5 encrypted by openssl enc -k?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69470583/it-is-possible-to-decrypt-aes-password-protected-file-in-c-sharp-dotnet-5-encr/69471070#69471070)
and Evk did some minor changes of the above answer (SHA256 instead of MD5, deal with the Salted__string, use byte[]) to make it work as a replacement of openSSL 1.1.1 (a to l)