# CryptDerive key with AES256

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

I am trying to re-create this openssl command in C#:

```
openssl enc –e –aes-256-cbc –k SecretPhrase1234 –in profile.xml –out profile.cfg
```

This encrypted file will then be loaded by a device and the process is described as this:

> A lower case –k precedes the secret key, which can be any plain text phrase and is used to generate a random 64-bit salt. Then, in combination with the secret specified with the –k argument, it derives a random 128-bit initial vector, and the actual 256-bit encryption key.

So, in my C# application I need to create a random 64 bit salt using my "SecretPhrase1234". Then I need to derive a 128 bit IV and a 256 bit key. The device already has the secret phrase loaded onto it.

Here is my code:

```
AesManaged aes = new AesManaged();

// Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
aes.KeySize = 256;
aes.BlockSize = 128;
aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("SecretPhrase1234", 8);
byte[] SALT = rfc.Salt;
PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes("SecretPhrase1234", SALT);               
byte[] IV = rfc.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize/8);
//The next line doesn't work
byte[] KEY = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("AES", "SHA1", aes.KeySize, IV); 
aes.Key = KEY;
aes.IV = IV;

byte[] encrypted = AESEncryption.EncryptStringToBytes(plainConfig, 
                                                    aes.Key, aes.IV);             
tw.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encrypted));
tw.Close();
```

Comment: What do you think is the problem? Did you read the error message? What does it tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a .NET implementation of OPENSSL which perfectly suits my needs. It is here:
[openssl using only .NET classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452422/openssl-using-only-net-classes)

Comment: Great you found something, but maybe wait a bit longer before posting?