# How to use AES Encryption in C# coming from PHP?

Tags: c#, php, aes

We have a project that required us to encrypt data to a 3rd party using PHP's openssl_encrypt function. However, we use C# to develop our apps.

```
$data = "hello world";
$key = ""very secret key;
base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($data, "aes-256-cbc", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA));
```

How can the same be achieved in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to know if there is "openssl_encrypt" in C# ?

Comment: Yes. If there's an equivalent function in C# for it.

Comment: So many Google search results for this...

Comment: I dont think theres build in support for that. You'll have to use a libary or write it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# has AES encryption built in.

but before using it you need to go through [Decrypt string in C# that was encrypted with PHP openssl_encrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719294/decrypt-string-in-c-sharp-that-was-encrypted-with-php-openssl-encrypt) - since

> PHP doesn't even use a key derivation algorithm [just takes the bytes of the passphrase and pads it out with zero's](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c86862cb3cd74cde1233630bbc7b97e276d68d28/ext/openssl/openssl.c#L5381)

Once you got your iv and key you can use AesManaged and CrytproStream to encrypt the data:

```
        byte[] iv = null; // get iv form pw
        byte[] key = null; // get key from pw
        using (AesManaged cryptor = new AesManaged())
        {

            ivhex = BitConverter.ToString(iv).Replace("-", string.Empty);
            keyhex = BitConverter.ToString(key).Replace("-", string.Empty);

            // Encrypt File
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                cryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                cryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                cryptor.KeySize = 256;
                cryptor.BlockSize = 256;

                //We use the random generated iv created by AesManaged
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream((Stream)ms, cryptor.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(cs))
                    {

                            swEncrypt.Write(text);

                    }
                }

                return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
```