# openssl_decrypt() for encryption c#

Tags: c#, php, encryption, openssl, decode

openssl_decrypt() is an already defined function php under the link

https://www.meridianoutpost.com/resources/etools/php-functions/php-openssl-decrypt.php?

I want this function to be implemented in c#

as the below already done in php

```
 public function decrypt($data, $password)
 {
     $iv = hex2bin(substr($data, 0, 16 * 2));
     $data = hex2bin(substr($data, 16 * 2));
     $plain_data = openssl_decrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $password, true, $iv);
     return $plain_data;
 }
```

c#

```
  public static string OpenSSLDecryptNew(string encrypted, string passphrase)
    {
        // base 64 decode
        byte[] encryptedBytesWithSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
        // extract salt (first 8 bytes of encrypted)
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[encryptedBytesWithSalt.Length - salt.Length - 8];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedBytesWithSalt, 8, salt, 0, salt.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedBytesWithSalt, salt.Length + 8, encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
        // get key and iv
        byte[] key, iv;
        DeriveKeyAndIV(passphrase, salt, out key, out iv);
        return DecryptStringFromBytesAes(encryptedBytes, key, iv);
    }

    private static void DeriveKeyAndIV(string passphrase, byte[] salt, out byte[] key, out byte[] iv)
    {
        // generate key and iv
        List<byte> concatenatedHashes = new List<byte>(48);

        byte[] password = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passphrase);
        byte[] currentHash = new byte[0];
        MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
        bool enoughBytesForKey = false;
        // See http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html#KEY_DERIVATION_ALGORITHM
        while (!enoughBytesForKey)
        {
            int preHashLength = currentHash.Length + password.Length + salt.Length;
            byte[] preHash = new byte[preHashLength];

            Buffer.BlockCopy(currentHash, 0, preHash, 0, currentHash.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(password, 0, preHash, currentHash.Length, password.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, preHash, currentHash.Length + password.Length, salt.Length);

            currentHash = md5.ComputeHash(preHash);
            concatenatedHashes.AddRange(currentHash);

            if (concatenatedHashes.Count >= 48)
                enoughBytesForKey = true;
        }

        key = new byte[32];
        iv = new byte[16];
        concatenatedHashes.CopyTo(0, key, 0, 32);
        concatenatedHashes.CopyTo(32, iv, 0, 16);

        md5.Clear();
    }

    static string DecryptStringFromBytesAes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("iv");

        // Declare the RijndaelManaged object
        // used to decrypt the data.
        RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext;

        // Create a RijndaelManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.None, KeySize = 256, BlockSize = 128, Key = key, IV = iv };

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        // Create the streams used for decryption.
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                    // and place them in a string.
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    srDecrypt.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        return plaintext;
    }
```

please refer to the above code , c# to decrypt same way as openssl_decrypt , i am asking if the same result will result based on c# and php and is there any c# code that return same behavior as openssl_decrypt() in php

Comment: Please post your most recent C# code and describe the problem.

Comment: To test any c# implementation it is important to present a sample dataset (ciphertext, password and resulting plaintext in PHP) as openssl does handle some things "curious" compared to c# (e.g. handling of too short/long passwords), thanks.

Comment: please refer to OpenSSLDecryptNew() function above , i am trying to find out same function as openssl_decrypt() in php that do the same job

Comment: These two codes really have nothing to do with each other. You simply posted the C# code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719294/decrypt-string-in-c-sharp-that-was-encrypted-with-php-openssl-encrypt). This is not a code delivery service. Please post a serious design. The PHP code is simple. It expects a hex encoded concatenation of IV and ciphertext. Both are to be separated for decryption.