# How to decrypt aes openssl encrypted file in C#

Tags: c#, openssl, aes

I have a file encrypted with openssl via:

```
openssl rand 32 -out key
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in input.json -out input.json.enc -pass file:key
```

How can I decrypt it in C#? Tried AesManaged with no luck.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you have tried with. It is important that you provide a [mcve] so that others can identify the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452422/openssl-encryption-using-net-classes