# c# openssl rsa -aes256 -in mykey.txt -out mykey_enc.txt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption, openssl, rsa

I'd to encrypt a txt file with openssl rsa aes256. I am planning to upload clear text file and encrypt with above technique. I have found similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452422/openssl-encryption-using-net-classes) but it seems bit different than my command in title.
By the way, the code can be written for string, not for file. I mean it may be like open ssl rsa256 in *stringclear* out *stringenc*

I will use the code in ASP.NET MVC application.