# How to decrypt files in Go that were encrypted using Openssl aes-256-cbc

Tags: go, encryption, openssl, aes

I am using OpenSSL AES-256-CBC to encrypt some of my files

`openssl aes-256-cbc -in filename.txt -out filename.enc -k password`

How can those files be decrypted in Go?

Comment: Have you tried doing something like this example here: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/#NewCBCDecrypter

Comment: OpenSSL uses a non-standard, insecure function to convert the password to an encryption key. One option is to derive the key yourself, and use the `-K` option. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/761902/3474 for details on how the built-in function works (you'd port that code to Go).

Comment: I'm not seeing the complexity here, why not just use OpenSSL bindings in Go? (such as https://godoc.org/github.com/spacemonkeygo/openssl)

Comment: @Woodstock Adding a dependency on OpenSSL (and all the pain that comes with cgo) just to decrypt a file is pretty overkill.  Go has very mature crypto support built-in.

Comment: You can try something like https://github.com/funny/crypto/blob/master/aes256cbc/aes256cbc.go

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help, make sure you read file bytes in *opensslEncrypted* variable:

**Installation**

```
git clone https://github.com/funny/crypto
```

**Decrypt:**

```
import (
  "fmt"
  "github.com/funny/crypto/aes256cbc"
)

func main() {
    opensslEncrypted := "U2FsdGVkX19ZM5qQJGe/d5A/4pccgH+arBGTp+QnWPU="
    passphrase := "z4yH36a6zerhfE5427ZV"

    dec, err := aes256cbc.DecryptString(passphrase, opensslEncrypted)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("An error occurred: %s\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Decrypted text: %s\n", string(dec))
}
```

Source: [github](https://github.com/funny/crypto/tree/master/aes256cbc)

Answer (score 0):

yes , it's working, but you cmd need run this

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -in filename.txt -out filename.enc -k password -a
```